# Pass a number as an argument into a stored procedure snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace procedure "Proc_Name"("Trgt_DB" VARCHAR,
    "Trgt_Schema" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Stage" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Timeframe" VARCHAR,
    "Trgt_Number_Timeframe" FLOAT)
returns string
language JavaScript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$

var remove_details = `delete from META.METADATA_TBL_META where last_modified <= DATEADD('` +Trgt_Timeframe+ `', -`+Trgt_Number_Timeframe+ `, current_date())`;
    var remove_details_sql = {sqlText: remove_details };
    var remove_details_create = snowflake.createStatement(remove_details_sql)
    var remove_details_exec = remove_details_create.execute();

return success;
$$;
```

```
CALL "Proc_Name('Dev', 'ACQ', 'Stage', 'days', 31);
```

I'm attempting to select all data from the table that is older than 31 days. The testing I've done shows hard coded variables works and the `Trgt_Timeframe` parameter works, I am having issues with the Trgt_Number_Timeframe as it is not deleting any data. Does anyone know how to format properly??

Comment: so is this meant to be a "Snowflake Scripting" Store Proc or JavaScript? Because this appears to be nether.

Comment: It's javascript scripting using backticks to implement parts for snowflake scripting, this isn't the full procedure, just the part thats giving an error

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but it makes it "harder" to help debug it, if I have to fill all the gaps.

Comment: Ah right okay, I'll update the post with more of the code

Comment: swapping in your SQL, the string is correctly built: `delete from META.METADATA_TBL_META where last_modified <= DATEADD('days', -31, current_date());` dropped two rows from my fake data.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure Proc_Name(
    "Trgt_DB" VARCHAR,
    "Trgt_Schema" VARCHAR, 
    "Trgt_Stage" VARCHAR, 
    "Trgt_Timeframe" VARCHAR,
    "Trgt_Number_Timeframe" FLOAT)
returns string not null
language javascript
  as
$$
    var sql = `select * from META.METADATA_TBL_META where last_modified <= DATEADD('` +Trgt_Timeframe+ `', -` +Trgt_Number_Timeframe+ `, current_date());`;
    return sql;
$$;
```

```
CALL Proc_Name('Dev', 'ACQ', 'Stage', 'days', 31);
```

gives me:

| PROC_NAME |
| --- |
| select * from META.METADATA_TBL_META where last_modified <= DATEADD('days', -31, current_date()); |

which when runs "works" for my fake data.

```
create schema meta;
create table meta.METADATA_TBL_META(id number, last_modified date);
insert into meta.METADATA_TBL_META values (1,'2022-04-16'::date),(2,'2022-03-16'::date),(3,'2022-02-16'::date);
```

| ID | LAST_MODIFIED |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-03-16 |
| 3 | 2022-02-16 |

### With Delete:

```
$$
    var sql = `select * from META.METADATA_TBL_META where last_modified <= DATEADD('` +Trgt_Timeframe+ `', -` +Trgt_Number_Timeframe+ `, current_date());`;
    var remove_details = `delete from META.METADATA_TBL_META where last_modified <= DATEADD('` +Trgt_Timeframe+ `', -`+Trgt_Number_Timeframe+ `, current_date())`;
    
    var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: remove_details } );
    var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
    result_set1.next();
    return result_set1.getColumnValue(1); 
$$;
```

```
CALL Proc_Name('Dev', 'ACQ', 'Stage', 'days', 31);
```

gives:

| PROC_NAME |
| --- |
| 2 |

Comment: Cheers, thank you, It started working, I'm unsure what the problem was with mine as above it's the same as the solution but possibly missing some form of backtick or something